# Change docker compose up name in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose

When running a `docker-compose.dcproj` project from the Visual Studio 2019 (using regular F5 Debug) it automatically executes this command (unrelated parts removed):
`docker-compose -f -p dockercompose5867848916081622061 up`
How do I force to regenerate this hash `dockercompose5867848916081622061` or replace it with my own value? The issue is that if the solution folder was copied from another project the containers are unable to respond to any incoming requests and just hang

UPD: changing this name didn't help me, getting a meaningful name would still be helpful though

Comment: Based on what MSFT team says, currently it's not configurable:
https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/171

Another option to control this name is to use `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable, but unfortunately, according to the docs, the CLI parameter `-p` still takes precedence:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/#compose-file-and-cli-variables

Comment: From looking at the github link that @AndreyCh provided, the Microsoft team have just implemented it in the last few days and it is pending release in v16.9 of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 30):

As of Visual Studio 16.9, you can use `<DockerComposeProjectName>my-docker-compose-project</DockerComposeProjectName>` in the `dcproj` file to specify the docker-compose project name.

See https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/171

Comment: This is the only correct answer in 2021 for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Works for VS 2022 as well!